# Visual Studio Code Quick Fix not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code to code for an app. I am using flutter to build the app. However, recently I have been unable to use the quick fix option to import files or fix simple errors. Previously I have not experienced this issue. I tried doing a clean re-install of VSC (and the plugins as well) but to no avail. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you so very much!

Comment: I am sorry I don't know what you mean by hand but if you mean like i tried to solve it not through the command line / shortcuts then yes (ie i uninstalled the extensions one by one then the whole software itself - although it did say preferences wouldn't be removed.)

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem when using the mouse to select a quick fix.  Instead of using the mouse use the keyboard:

1. Place the cursor on the error.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>
3. Use the keyboard to select your fix.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is a good temporary fix - i am more accustomed to using mouse when doing this kinds of quick fixes. So hopefully a fix is around the corner. But thank you for this option too!